# How do I identify this 30 pin connector on split keyboard?

Tags: identification, connector, cables

I have a split keyboard (Goldtouch sk2730). The cable connecting the two halfs is a little short for my purposes.

I open up one side of the split and see this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What is the name of this connector and would there be a significant disadvantage to getting a, say, 1m version of the cable it attaches?

EDIT - extra pictures as requested :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: My guess is Hirose makes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the pitch: 1 mm.

I identified it with [my connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&fl=00120030000000000000202000100000-55c-%7C1%7C30%7C%7C%7C).

It's a [JST SHD](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=232)

- [Male PCB header](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/SM30B-SRDS-G-TF-LF-SN/926773)
- [Female plug housing](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/jst-sales-america-inc/SHDR-30V-S-B/759926)

[image: JSD SHD] {Digikey}

Comment: That looks awesome. Thank you! I've added extra pictures with measurement

Comment: I'm almost certain it is JST, SHD series https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=232. But I guess there can be compatible sources from several manufacturers.

Comment: _I've added extra pictures with measurement_. Thank you. The pitch is 1 mm.

Comment: Please see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually go to component supplier search tool and enter number of positions, number of rows, pitch between contacts, if it's a jack or plug and hope to identify it in the search result pictures.